# where i am wrong in given program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, std

Here is my program to find all the subsets of given set. To solve it, I used recursion.
But when I compiled it in windows on codeblocks. It gives

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in a
>   unusual way.

and in gcc compiler it didn't show any answer, no response.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> findAllSubset(char c, vector<string> v) {
    int size = v.size();
    if(size == 1) {
        v.push_back("");
        return v;
    }
    c = v[size-1][0];
    v.pop_back();
    v = findAllSubset(c, v);

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        string s= "";
        if(v[i].size() == 0){
            s += c;
            v.push_back(s);
        }
        else {
            s += v[i] + c;
            v.push_back( s );
        }
    }
    return v;
}

main() {
    vector<string> v, ans;
    char c = 65;
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    //v.push_back("c");
    //v.push_back("d");
    ans = findAllSubset(c, v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't pass `vector<string>` by value.

Comment: Then how can I pass a set of strings?

Comment: By using **reference**. Also, if you really mean set, there's `std::set<>` container. I didn't really understand your algorithm there, but certainly your usage of standard library is inefficient.

Comment: First, it's "vector", not "set"; second, by reference, of course. @nhahtdh, I don't know what you mean, but you obviously can push `const char *` into `vector<string>`...

Comment: The first problem here is that the program flow in the function is far from obvious. Even without bugs this would be a nightmare to maintain. Your first step should be to make the logic obvious – both in your head, and then translated into code. This will probably also clear up the error.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, it's not called STL, m'kay? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571

Comment: As a note, I don't really understand how should your algorithm work; you have problem at algorithm level, not at source level.

Comment: How can you do `c = v[size-1][0];` on a vector? What does this mean? And it seems there is an infinite loop in your function `findAllSubset`

Comment: @Sanish: That'll be the first character of the (size-1)th string.

Comment: Is there any other way to improve this algorithm? (To decrease time coplexity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for loop is an infinite loop, each time an element is push_back in the vector, vector size increases making the condition i < v.size() is always true.

Answer (score 2):

You keep pushing strings to your vector while you loop through it. There is the infinite loop. It is generally a bad idea to alter a container while looping through it.

Comment: Well, if he had some kind of assertion when to finish the loop, his loop would be perfectly valid, as he uses indices, not iterators, and only adds elements into his vector. But yup, the problem is that there is no such assertion.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an infinite loop. The program compiles and runs normally but never exits